# Spring Boot: change from Java Servlet 3.1 to 3.0

Tags: spring-boot, servlet-3.0, spring-boot-maven-plugin

In Eclipse (STS) I created a project as follows:
File -> New -> Spring Starter Project

The settings are (among others):
Type: Maven Project
Packaging: War
Java Version: 1.8
Language: Java
Boot Version: 1.3.0
Dependencies: Web

In the project facets it leads to Dynamic Web Module = 3.1, however I need 3.0.

Manually setting it to 3.0 leads to "Cannot change version of project facet Dynamic Web Module to 3.0".
Besides this error message I am sure this is not the right way to change it because the project will be shared to others.

I guess there is a maven way.
Maybe the solution is somewhere here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.0.RELEASE/maven-plugin/plugin-info.html.

Unfortunately Spring Boot and Maven are not my special topics (yet).

Answer (score 0):

Not the correct way but, the easiest way to fix that issue is 'Delete' that error from the 'Problems' tab. It will be removed and your code will be compiled on STS. But, it may come back at some point then just delete that error again.